# Using chart in ALP but it can't load data properly when the data comes more than 1000

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

Currently I'm using line chart in ALP, and I'm using time as x-axis, so when it comes with many  data of time(>=1000 ) ,the chart loads data only in 130, and the more weird thing is that when I switch chart into some kind else ,like column chart, the data shown in the chart has changed to 180, and so on. In the same time, the data shown the table above loads correctly. I cannot find any issue or tip on the document or in the community.
P.S This issue happened only when the data(x-axis) reaches 1000 and more, 999 and the below are all aright.

My Ui5 version is 1.109.0, and using cap-node as backend.

I've try to change the version of UI5, but comes with no change.

I hope that you can tell me why this thing happens , and you can try to see the issue on local through  a simple demo I found on the github https://github.wdf.sap.corp/PoC-LowCode-NoCode/alp_poc. Choose node as backend and add data to the my.bookshop-Books.csvfile(https://gist.github.com/OiverCai/aee8f7c75e382f0554d9746785ba45dd)
then rewrite the dimension in  cat-service-ui.cds from title to ID(x-axis), then start the project and you can see the issue.

Comment: This limitation is likely due to the performance of the charting library being used by ALP, One of the solution is try to use different library for charting like d3.js, amchart, chart.js etc, which may have better performance

Comment: Thank you, your advice is helpful. I plan to try in another way.